# What do I do when install doesn't seem to complete?

Tags: configuration, windows, help

Cannot get Tor to start\open after install.  I have both d\l's available to use for my install; neither apparently works, or I am missing something.  If I use the 'wizard' installer, it gives me 4-5 'error' messages, saying that I am missing certain files.  If I use the 'non-wizard' package, it go thru the whole procedure, opens a "cmd" window, that runs thru it's sequence, then stops. Nothing more opens.

I am running Windows 10, plenty of space for the install available, as is RAM & processor capability.

Comment: We need some more information to answer your question: What software did you download from which place? What did you do after you downloaded it? Can you provide a screenshot? Thanks.